# Nested while loop only iterates once

Tags: python

I have written some code which takes data from a csv file, stores it in lists, then iterates over the data returning only the information I need.
I had it working for single lists:

```
# Import modules
import csv
import datetime
# import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Time code (as slow to run)
tin = []
tout = []
tin = datetime.datetime.now() #tic
plt.close()

# Assign variables
pktime = []
pkey1 = []
pkey2 = []
pkey3 = []
pkey4 = []
pkey5 = []
pkey6 = []
pkeys=[pkey1, pkey2, pkey3, pkey4, pkey5, pkey6]
delt1 = []
delt2 = []
delt3 = []
delt4 = []
delt5 = []
delt6 = []
delts=[delt1, delt2, delt3, delt4, delt5, delt6]
pkey1full=[]
pkey2full=[]
pkey3full=[]
pkey4full=[]
pkey5full=[]
pkey6full=[]
pkeyfull=[pkey1full, pkey2full, pkey3full, pkey4full, pkey5full, pkey6full]


# Read in PK weight/deltaT/time values
with open('PKweight.csv') as pkweight:
    red = csv.reader(pkweight)
    for t, pk1, pk2, pk3, pk4, pk5, pk6, dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4, dt5, dt6 in red:

        pktime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(t,'%H:%M:%S'))
        pkey1.append(float(pk1))
        pkey2.append(float(pk2))
        pkey3.append(float(pk3))
        pkey4.append(float(pk4))
        pkey5.append(float(pk5))
        pkey6.append(float(pk6))
        delt1.append(float(dt1))
        delt2.append(float(dt2))
        delt3.append(float(dt3))
        delt4.append(float(dt4))
        delt5.append(float(dt5))
        delt6.append(float(dt6))

#calculate the pkweight for each cell, then append it to pkey*full

def pkweight1_calc():
    i=1
    while i<=(len(pkey1)-1):
        if pkey1[i] == 0.0 and pkey1[i-1]!=0.0:
            pkey1full.append(pkey1[i-2])
        i+=1
    pkey1full.reverse()
    return pkey1full
pkweight1_calc()
```

I had this code written out 6 times to complete the function for each of the sets of data(1-6), however I want to have it all as one function. I have tried using a nested while loop within a while loop, however it only returns  one of the lists, whatever the inital value of j was:

```
def pkweight_calc():    
    i=1
    for j in range(0,5):
        while i<=(len(pkeys[j])-1):
            if (pkeys[j][i]) == 0.0 and (pkeys[j][i-1])!=0.0:
                pkeyfull[j].append(pkeys[j][i-2])
            i+=1
        pkeyfull[j].reverse()
pkweight_calc()
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!!
EDIT- updated indenting, Sorry!

Comment: Is this the actual indentation you have in your code? because as written it is an infinite loop.

Comment: Also look at this line `pkey1full.append(pkey1[i-2])` , for is not it trying to access pkey1[-1] for `i=1`?

Comment: why u write as an infinite loop.what actually you needs

Comment: SORRY, indenting was wrong when uploaded to here should be fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, I managed to find someone at work who could help me. He wasnt sure why but changing the while loop

```
while i<=(len(pkeys[j])-1):
```

to a for loop:

```
for i in range(2, len(pkeys[j])):
```

solved it. Not sure why but it did!